# Разбор статистики логов статистики

Tags: php

Есть подобные записи в логе статистики -

> <- 21.03.2016 (15:10:30)|127.0.0.1|Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36|domain.ru|referer ->

Разбираю записи в режиме реального времени без затаскиваний промежуточных результатов в базу(в будущем подумаю над этим).

Поясните: Как правильно разбирать по частям эти данные.Например,при разборе получить: `сколько всего посетителей за сегодня\за неделю\вчера`,`сколько всего посетителей зашло на определенный домен(domain.ru) за сегодня\за неделю\вчера`.

Кое-как решил проблему...Цепочка такая: разобрать на отдельные записи->узнать сколько всего за вчера и сегодня людей по дате(а как тогда выбрать за неделю?).Для выборки для доменов происходят похожие операции...но это криво как по мне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше всего хранить такую информацию по суткам, просто завести ассоциативный массив и увеличивать ключи, для элемента с ключом, равным текущим суткам.

```
2016-03-21  100532
2016-03-20   93243
2016-03-22  103423
...
```

Если у вас не подсчитываются уникальные хосты/IP-адреса, а считается просто сумма посещений, то сумма за последние 7 дней даст количество посещений за неделю - суммируем последние 7 элементов. Если вы считаете хосты (уникальные IP-адреса), то такой подход будет неточен, так как один и тот IP-адрес может встречаться в нескольких днях. Придется заводить под недели отдельный ассоциативный массив.

Для хранения и обработки этой информации, вместо медленной базы данных, можно воспользоваться быстрым NoSQL решением, например, Redis. Особенностью большинства NoSQL баз является то, что данные хранятся в оперативной памяти - т.е. обсчет производится очень быстро даже перебором, так как если бы данные находились в памяти вашей программы. Плюс многие NoSQL базы обладают агрегационными возможностями. Например, при помощи множеств вы можете сразу отбирать только уникальные значения, складируя записи в массив с ключом равным временному интервалу, можно потом извлекать суммы по ним. Самое главное все в оперативной памяти и очень быстро.